# Angular render component depending on url

Tags: javascript, angular, seo, angular9

I have an Angular 9 single page website. This page contain multiple component rendered with angular universal. All blocks are rendered one after another.

Let's say I have these component: header, services, contact, footer.
In my header I have a link to all component as anchor.

To optimize my SEO, I would like to render all block for users, but only the block linked to the anchor for search engine crawlers.

For example,on mywebsite.com/contact :
As an user I would render all component but I would be at the contact anchor.
As a crawler, I would only render header, contact and footer

I searched everywhere but I cant find a way to do that properly, even that it seems like a thing everyone who want to optimize their SEO should do.

Am I missing something or do you have a way to do that ?

**EDIT :**

By using ng-template I can show one component or all with a condition.

For this condition I need to get the user agent but I cant find a way to get it with Angular Universal.
navigator.userAgent doesn't work since it's the website is rendered by the server.

Since I'm new to Angular I dont know how to get that information. Any help ?

Comment: try angular router, resolve?

Comment: I use it but I don't know how to serve differently to users and crawlers

Comment: If I understand right, you can use resolve, then get the prams from resolve in each components, use [hidden] to bind the value from params to control whether this component should be shown.